# Export data from SQL Server view to table with additional header row

Tags: sql-server, database, export

I am using a view to feed a table in my database. While feeding the table, I am also adding a header row to the table. I am doing this for 5 tables.

However, for 2 tables, I could see that the header row in inserted at the top most where as for remaining 5 tables, the header row goes down. How can I fix it?

This is the query I am using to feed the data. I could see the header as 1st row in the JOB and EMPJOB tables.

```
INSERT INTO [JOB_Export](Job_Cd, Job_Name, Job_Note, Job_URL, OptJob_Currency, Domain_OrgCd, OptJob_Txt1, OptJob_Txt2, OptJob_Txt3, OptJob_Txt4, OptJob_Dt1, OptJob_Dt2, OptJob_Int1, OptJob_MONEY, OptJob_FLOAT1, OptJob_Ind1, OptJob_Memo1) 
    SELECT 
        'JOB_CODE' AS "JOB_CODE", 'JOB_NAME' AS "JOB_NAME",
        'JOB_DESC' AS "JOB_DESC", 'JOB_URL' AS "JOB_URL",
        'JOB_CURRENCY_CD' AS "JOB_CURRENCY_CD", 'JOB_DOMAIN' AS "JOB_DOMAIN", 
        'CUSTOM_TEXT1' AS "CUSTOM_TEXT1", 'CUSTOM_TEXT2' AS "CUSTOM_TEXT2",
        'CUSTOM_TEXT3' AS "CUSTOM_TEXT3", 'CUSTOM_TEXT4' AS "CUSTOM_TEXT4",
        'CUSTOM_DATE1' AS "CUSTOM_DATE1", 'CUSTOM_DATE2' AS "CUSTOM_DATE2",
        'CUSTOM_INTEGER1' AS "CUSTOM_INTEGER1", 'CUSTOM_MONEY1'AS "CUSTOM_MONEY1", 
        'CUSTOM_FLOAT1' AS "CUSTOM_FLOAT1", 'CUSTOM_IND1' AS "CUSTOM_IND1",
        'CUSTOM_MEMO1' AS "CUSTOM_MEMO1" 
    UNION
    SELECT  
        RTRIM(Job_Cd),
        Job_Name,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(MAX),Job_Note) Job_Note,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(255), Job_URL) Job_URL, 
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), OptJob_Currency) OptJob_Currency,
        Domain_OrgCd, 
        OptJob_Txt1,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(255), OptJob_Txt2) OptJob_Txt2, 
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(255), OptJob_Txt3)  OptJob_Txt3 ,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(255), OptJob_Txt4)  OptJob_Txt4 ,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(500), OptJob_Dt1)  OptJob_Dt1 , 
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(500), OptJob_Dt2)  OptJob_Dt2 , 
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(500), OptJob_Int1)  OptJob_Int1 ,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(500), OptJob_MONEY) OptJob_MONEY ,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(500), OptJob_FLOAT1) OptJob_FLOAT1,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(500), OptJob_Ind1)  OptJob_Ind1 ,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(MAX), OptJob_Memo1)   OptJob_Memo1 
    FROM 
        [OVERRIDE_JOB_VIEW] 

INSERT INTO [EMPJOB_Export](Emp_No,Job_Cd,EmpJob_JoiningDate,EmpJob_PrmyInd,Domain_Cd)
SELECT 'EMP_NO' AS "EMP_NO",'JOB_CODE' AS "JOB_CODE",'JOIN_DATE' AS"JOIN_DATE",'PRIMARY' AS "PRIMARY",'JOB_DOMAIN' AS "JOB_DOMAIN"
UNION
SELECT [Emp_No], 
    CASE    WHEN LEN(Job_Cd)<=30 THEN CONVERT (VARCHAR(500), JOB_CD) 
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),SUBSTRING(rtrim([Job_Cd]),1,30))
    END AS Job_Cd,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),[EmpJob_JoiningDate]) [EmpJob_JoiningDate] ,
    [EmpJob_PrmyInd],
    CASE    WHEN LEN(rtrim([Domain_Cd]))<=50 THEN [Domain_Cd]
    ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim([Domain_Cd]),1,50)
    END AS [Domain_Cd]
    FROM [EMPJOB_VIEW]



INSERT INTO [EMPORG_Export] (Emp_No,Org_Cd,EmpOrg_JoiningDate,EmpOrg_RoleName,EmpOrg_PrmyInd,EmpOrg_DomainInd) 
SELECT 'EMP_NO' AS "EMP_NO",'ORG_CODE' AS "ORG_CODE",'JOIN_DATE' AS "JOIN_DATE",'ROLE' AS "ROLE",'PRIMARY' AS "PRIMARY",'DOMAIN' AS "DOMAIN"
UNION   
SELECT  [Emp_No],rtrim([Org_Cd]) AS [Org_Cd],[EmpOrg_JoiningDate],[EmpOrg_RoleName],    [EmpOrg_PrmyInd],[EmpOrg_DomainInd] FROM [EmpOrg_View]


INSERT INTO [ORG_Export]
(Org_Cd,Org_Name,POrg_Cd,HierType_Name,Org_DomainInd,Org_Note,Org_URL,Org_Add1,Org_Add2,Org_City,Org_State,Org_Zip,Org_Cntry,Org_Phn1,Org_Phn2,Org_Fax,OptOrg_Txt1,OptOrg_Txt2,OptOrg_Txt3,OptOrg_Txt4,OptOrg_Dt1,OptOrg_Dt2,OptOrg_Int1,OptOrg_FLOAT1,OptOrg_Ind1,OptOrg_MONEY,OptOrg_Memo1,OptOrg_Currency)
SELECT  'ORG_CODE'              AS "ORG_CODE",
    'ORG_NAME'              AS "ORG_NAME",
    'ORG_PARENT_CODE'       AS "ORG_PARENT_CODE",
    'HIERARCHY'             AS  "HIERARCHY",
    'DOMAIN_FLAG'           AS "DOMAIN_FLAG",
    'NOTE'                  AS "NOTE",
    'ORG_URL'               AS "ORG_URL",
    'ADDRESS1'              AS "ADDRESS1",
    'ADDRESS2'              AS "ADDRESS2",
    'CITY'                  AS "CITY",
    'STATE'                 AS "STATE",
    'ZIP'                   AS "ZIP",
    'COUNTRY'               AS "COUNTRY",
    'PHONE1'                AS "PHONE1",
    'PHONE2'                AS "PHONE2",
    'FAX'                   AS "FAX",
    'CUSTOM_TEXT1'          AS "CUSTOM_TEXT1",
    'CUSTOM_TEXT2'          AS "CUSTOM_TEXT2",
    'CUSTOM_TEXT3'          AS "CUSTOM_TEXT3",
    'CUSTOM_TEXT4'          AS "CUSTOM_TEXT4",
    'CUSTOM_DATE1'          AS "CUSTOM_DATE1",
    'CUSTOM_DATE2'          AS "CUSTOM_DATE2",
    'CUSTOM_INTEGER1'       AS "CUSTOM_INTEGER1",
    'CUSTOM_FLOAT1'         AS "CUSTOM_FLOAT1",
    'CUSTOM_IND1'           AS "CUSTOM_IND1",
    'CUSTOM_MONEY1'         AS "CUSTOM_MONEY1",
    'CUSTOM_MEMO1'          AS "CUSTOM_MEMO1",
    'CUSTOM_CURRENCY_CODE'  AS "CUSTOM_CURRENCY_CODE"
UNION
SELECT rtrim([Org_Cd]) AS [Org_Cd],[Org_Name],[POrg_Cd],[HierType_Name],
CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM([Org_DomainInd]))=1  THEN RTRIM([Org_DomainInd])
        ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim([Org_DomainInd]),1,1)
END AS [Org_DomainInd],
[Org_Note],[Org_URL],[Org_Add1],[Org_Add2], 
CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM([Org_City]))<=30 THEN RTRIM([Org_City])
        ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim([Org_City]),1,30)
END AS [Org_City],
[Org_State],[Org_Zip],[Org_Cntry],  
CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM([Org_Phn1]))<=30 THEN RTRIM([Org_Phn1])
        ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim([Org_Phn1]),1,30)
END AS [Org_Phn2],
CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM([Org_Phn2]))<=30 THEN RTRIM([Org_Phn2])
        ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim([Org_Phn2]),1,30)
END AS [Org_Phn2],
CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM([Org_Fax]))<=30 THEN RTRIM([Org_Fax])
        ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim([Org_Fax]),1,30)
END AS [Org_Fax],   
[OptOrg_Txt1],
[OptOrg_Txt2],[OptOrg_Txt3],[OptOrg_Txt4],[OptOrg_Dt1], [OptOrg_Dt2],[OptOrg_Int1],[OptOrg_FLOAT1],
CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM([OptOrg_Ind1]))=1  THEN RTRIM([OptOrg_Ind1])
        ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim([OptOrg_Ind1]),1,1)
END AS [OptOrg_Ind1],
[OptOrg_MONEY],[OptOrg_Memo1],[OptOrg_Currency]
FROM [Org_View]



INSERT INTO [EMP_Export]
(Emp_No,Emp_Title,Emp_LName,Emp_FName,Emp_MI,Emp_Suffix,Emp_Ttl,EmpCd_Name,EmpStat_Name,Mgr_No,DefApprEmp_No,Emp_StartDt,Emp_EndDt,Emp_LastRvwDt,Emp_Add1,Emp_Add2,Emp_City,Emp_State,Emp_Zip,Emp_Cntry,Emp_Email,Emp_Phn1,Emp_Phn2,Emp_Fax,Emp_URL,Emp_Note,EmpDomain_Cd,Org_Cd,Job_Cd,Emp_Active,Usr_Enabled,Usr_Name,Usr_NTLogin,Role_Name,Usr_Timezone,Usr_Currency,Usr_Language,OptEmp_Txt1,OptEmp_Txt2,OptEmp_Txt3,OptEmp_Txt4,OptEmp_Memo1,OptEmp_Dt1,OptEmp_Dt2,OptEmp_Ind1,OptEmp_MONEY,OptEmp_Int1,OptEmp_FLOAT1,Emp_Job_JoiningDate,PublishCalendar,ViewAllEmpsInd,IsMobileEnabled,MobileUserName)
SELECT  'EMP_NO'                AS "EMP_NO"
    ,'NAME_PREFIX_TEXT'     AS "NAME_PREFIX_TEXT"
    ,'LAST_NAME'            AS "LAST_NAME"
    ,'FIRST_NAME'           AS "FIRST_NAME"
    ,'MIDDLE_NAME'          AS "MIDDLE_NAME"
    ,'NAME_SUFFIX_TEXT'     AS "NAME_SUFFIX_TEXT"
    ,'CUSTOM_TEXT5'         AS "CUSTOM_TEXT5"
    ,'USER_CODE_TEXT'       AS "USER_CODE_TEXT"
    ,'USER_STATUS_TEXT'     AS "USER_STATUS_TEXT"
    ,'MANAGER_NO'           AS "MANAGER_NO"
    ,'TRNG_DEF_APPROVER_NO' AS "TRNG_DEF_APPROVER_NO"
    ,'START_DATE'           AS "START_DATE"
    ,'END_DATE'             AS "END_DATE"
    ,'LAST_REVIEW_DATE'     AS "LAST_REVIEW_DATE"
    ,'WORK_ADDRESS1'        AS "WORK_ADDRESS1"
    ,'WORK_ADDRESS2'        AS "WORK_ADDRESS2"
    ,'WORK_CITY'            AS "WORK_CITY"
    ,'WORK_STATE_TEXT'      AS "WORK_STATE_TEXT"
    ,'WORK_ZIP'             AS "WORK_ZIP"
    ,'WORK_COUNTRY_TEXT'    AS "WORK_COUNTRY_TEXT"
    ,'EMAIL'                AS "EMAIL"
    ,'WORK_PHONE'           AS "WORK_PHONE"
    ,'WORK_PHONE_EXT'       AS "WORK_PHONE_EXT"
    ,'WORK_FAX1'            AS "WORK_FAX1"
    ,'URL'                  AS "URL"
    ,'NOTES'                AS "NOTES"
    ,'PRIMARY_DOMAIN'       AS "PRIMARY_DOMAIN"
    ,'PRIMARY_ORG'          AS "PRIMARY_ORG"
    ,'PRIMARY_JOB'          AS "PRIMARY_JOB"
    ,'ACTIVE_FLAG'          AS "ACTIVE_FLAG"
    ,'LOGIN_ENABLED_FLAG'   AS "LOGIN_ENABLED_FLAG"
    ,'LOGIN_USERNAME'       AS "LOGIN_USERNAME"
    ,'NT_LOGIN'             AS "NT_LOGIN"
    ,'SECURITY_ROLE'        AS "SECURITY_ROLE"
    ,'TIMEZONE_CD'          AS "TIMEZONE_CD"
    ,'CURRENCY_TEXT'        AS "CURRENCY_TEXT"
    ,'LOCALE_CD'            AS "LOCALE_CD"
    ,'CUSTOM_TEXT1'         AS "CUSTOM_TEXT1"
    ,'CUSTOM_TEXT2'         AS "CUSTOM_TEXT2"
    ,'CUSTOM_TEXT3'         AS "CUSTOM_TEXT3"
    ,'CUSTOM_TEXT4'         AS "CUSTOM_TEXT4"
    ,'CUSTOM_MEMO1'         AS "CUSTOM_MEMO1"
    ,'CUSTOM_DATE1'         AS "CUSTOM_DATE1"
    ,'CUSTOM_DATE2'         AS "CUSTOM_DATE2"
    ,'CUSTOM_IND1'          AS "CUSTOM_IND1"
    ,'CUSTOM_MONEY1'        AS "CUSTOM_MONEY1"
    ,'CUSTOM_INTEGER1'      AS "CUSTOM_INTEGER1"
    ,'CUSTOM_FLOAT1'        AS "CUSTOM_FLOAT1"
    ,'PRIMARY_JOB_JOINDATE' AS "PRIMARY_JOB_JOINDATE"
    ,'AUTO_PUBLISH_CAL'     AS "AUTO_PUBLISH_CAL"
    ,'CAN_VIEW_ALL_USERS_FLAG' AS "CAN_VIEW_ALL_USERS_FLAG"
    ,'MOBILE_ENABLED'       AS "MOBILE_ENABLED"
    ,'MOBILE_USERNAME'      AS "MOBILE_USERNAME"
UNION
SELECT      Emp_No,
        Emp_Title,
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(Emp_LName)) <= 50  THEN RTRIM(Emp_LName)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(Emp_LName),1,50)
        END AS Emp_LName,
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(Emp_FName)) <= 50  THEN RTRIM(Emp_FName)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(Emp_FName),1,50)
        END AS Emp_FName,
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(Emp_MI)) <= 50  THEN RTRIM(Emp_MI)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(Emp_MI),1,50)
        END AS Emp_MI,
        Emp_Suffix,
        Emp_Ttl     ,
        EmpCd_Name  ,       
        EmpStat_Name,
        Mgr_No      ,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(25),DefApprEmp_No) DefApprEmp_No,
        Emp_StartDt ,
        Emp_EndDt   ,
        Emp_LastRvwDt,
        Emp_Add1    ,
        Emp_Add2    ,
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(Emp_City)) <= 50  THEN RTRIM(Emp_City)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(Emp_City),1,50)
        END AS Emp_City,    
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(Emp_State)) <= 35  THEN RTRIM(Emp_State)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(Emp_State),1,35)
        END AS Emp_State,
        Emp_Zip     ,
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(Emp_Cntry)) <= 50  THEN RTRIM(Emp_Cntry)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(Emp_Cntry),1,50)
        END AS Emp_Cntry,
        Emp_Email,
         Emp_Phn1,
         Emp_Phn2,
         Emp_Fax,
         Emp_URL,
         Emp_Note       ,
         EmpDomain_Cd   ,
         rtrim(Org_Cd)  ,
         CONVERT (VARCHAR(500),rtrim(Job_Cd)) Job_Cd    ,
         Emp_Active     ,
         Usr_Enabled    ,
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(Usr_Name)) <= 85  THEN RTRIM(Usr_Name)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(Usr_Name),1,85)
        END AS Usr_Name,
         Usr_NTLogin    ,
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(Role_Name)) <= 100  THEN RTRIM(Role_Name)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(Role_Name),1,100)
        END AS Role_Name,
         Usr_Timezone   ,
         Usr_Currency   ,
         Usr_Language   ,
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(OptEmp_Txt1)) <= 255  THEN RTRIM(OptEmp_Txt1)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(OptEmp_Txt1),1,255)
        END AS OptEmp_Txt1,
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(OptEmp_Txt2)) <= 255  THEN RTRIM(OptEmp_Txt2)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(OptEmp_Txt2),1,255)
        END AS OptEmp_Txt2,
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(OptEmp_Txt3)) <= 255  THEN RTRIM(OptEmp_Txt3)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(OptEmp_Txt3),1,255)
        END AS OptEmp_Txt3,
        CASE    WHEN LEN(RTRIM(OptEmp_Txt4)) <= 255  THEN RTRIM(OptEmp_Txt4)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(rtrim(OptEmp_Txt4),1,255)
        END AS OptEmp_Txt4,
         OptEmp_Memo1   ,
         OptEmp_Dt1 ,
         OptEmp_Dt2 ,
         CONVERT (VARCHAR(500),OptEmp_Ind1) OptEmp_Ind1, 
        OptEmp_MONEY,
        OptEmp_Int1, 
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(500),OptEmp_FLOAT1) OptEmp_FLOAT1, 
        Emp_Job_JoiningDate,
        PublishCalendar,
        ViewAllEmpsInd  ,
        IsMobileEnabled ,
        MobileUserName  
FROM [Employee_VIEW]
```

Comment: You can provide some sort order to the values so your header row remains at top.

Comment: Can you please to give a try, changing UNION to UNION ALL? Since your header record is unlikely to duplicate with your real records.

Answer (score 0):

Without using ORDER clause the result returned from a SELECT in MSSQL Server is always ordered randomly. You sometimes see the same result when executing a query multiple times because of the MSSQL Server caching capabilities (plan cache).

You can use additional column to do the sortings on, you can rely on ORDER, RANK or something that will suit you best.